# Handling views in SplitView

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4, uisplitviewcontroller

What is the correct method to handle the scenario where we have to show different views(controlled by different view controllers) on selecting each row of the rootview in a splitview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RootViewController you have a table view delegate selector called:

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Splitview controller is slightly different from the TableView + Nav pattern (it's more like the Tab bar). You must change the SplitViewController's viewControllers property to set the viewController for the selected row. In the DetailViewController you can manage the memory allocated for that selection. More: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html

Comment: What about memory management when we switch between different views?And i dont think we can push views, as we donot have a navigation controller